# How Do I Permanently Set "collation_connection" To utf8mb4_unicode_ci?

Tags: mysql

I have made changes to my.cnf to use **utf8mb4** and **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**.

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
init-connect = 'SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

However, when I run:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

this is the response.

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

As you can see, the collation_connection is **utf8mb4_general_ci** but I want it to be **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**.

At the moment, the only workaround is for me to run:

```
SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

But as soon as the MySQL server is restarted, it reverts back to **utf8mb4_general_ci**.

Is there a permanent way to set the collation-connection to **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm stuck on the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your config key "init-connect" is not true, it should be "init_connect"